# OpenSeaDragon with Featherlight on MOBILE (Chrome on Android). Modal window immediately close after display

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, featherlight.js, openseadragon

Im fighting with this error about 1 week.
http://karoleekk.cfolks.pl/final/index2.html

This website have images-tiles based of OpenSeaDragon. Next - after click - I have modal from https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/ .
On PC everything working very well. No errors or something like that.

But, when I lunch this website in Chrome at Android... ehh. the biggest error is goin on.
After click modal show about 0.1 sec and immediately closes. I think something is bad with OpenSeaDragon but... dont know where to start searching solution.

Someone can help me, please?!
Like I said before - im trying to slove this problem about one week.

Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm familiar with OpenSeadragon but not Featherlight or Android Chrome. I can't think of anything in OpenSeadragon that would cause this. My recommendation would be to make a version without OpenSeadragon and see if you can still reproduce the issue... try to isolate the problem. Sorry I'm not more help!

Comment: For the sake of crosslinking, I'm noting that this question is asked here as well: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/2016